# Como utilizar uma variável em todo o escopo do batch SQL

Tags: sql-server

Com o batch abaixo, desejo remover os registros duplicados e após isso efetuar um UPDATE em alguns valores. As querys estão em perfeita ordem, mas adicionando algumas verificações de erro para a execução do processo, me deparei com o seguinte erro:

> Must declare the scalar variable "@erroDelete".

Como posso declarar a variável para que seja utilizada em todo o escopo?

```
DECLARE @erroDelete INT
SET @erroDelete = 0 

PRINT 'Deletando registros duplicados.'

BEGIN TRY
    DELETE t
    FROM produtos_sumario t
    INNER JOIN produtos ON t.cod_produto = produtos.cod_produto
    WHERE produtos.cod_empresa <> t.cod_grupo

    DELETE t
    FROM logistica_sumario t
    INNER JOIN produtos ON t.cod_produto = produtos.cod_produto
    WHERE produtos.cod_empresa <> t.cod_grupo

    DELETE t
    FROM cubo t
    INNER JOIN produtos ON t.cod_produto = produtos.cod_produto
    WHERE produtos.cod_empresa <> t.cod_grupo

    DELETE t
    FROM cubo_rentabilidade t
    INNER JOIN produtos ON t.cod_produto = produtos.cod_produto
    WHERE produtos.cod_empresa <> t.cod_grupo

END TRY
BEGIN CATCH
    PRINT 'Falha ao deletar registros';
    PRINT 'Erro ' + CONVERT(VARCHAR, ERROR_NUMBER(), 1) + ': '+ ERROR_MESSAGE()
    SET @erroDelete = 1 
END CATCH
GO

/* ATUALIZAR REGISTROS COM NOVO CÓDIGO DE GRUPO DOS PRODUTOS */

IF (@erroDelete = 0)

    PRINT 'Atualizando registros.'

    BEGIN TRY
        /* TABELA Acordos_GR */
        UPDATE t
        SET t.cod_grupo = p.cod_empresa
        FROM Acordos_GR t
        JOIN produtos p ON p.cod_produto = t.cod_produto
        WHERE p.cod_produto = t.cod_produto

        /* TABELA submetas */
        UPDATE t
        SET t.cod_grupo = p.cod_empresa
        FROM submetas t
        JOIN produtos p ON p.cod_produto = t.cod_produto
        WHERE p.cod_produto = t.cod_produto

        /* TABELA metas_vendedores */
        UPDATE t
        SET t.cod_grupo = p.cod_empresa
        FROM metas_vendedores t
        JOIN produtos p ON p.cod_produto = t.cod_produto

        /* TABELA metas_simulacao */
        UPDATE t
        SET t.cod_grupo = p.cod_empresa
        FROM metas_simulacao t
        JOIN produtos p ON p.cod_produto = t.cod_produto

        /* TABELA metas_orcada */
        UPDATE t
        SET t.cod_grupo = p.cod_empresa
        FROM metas_orcada t
        JOIN produtos p ON p.cod_produto = t.cod_produto
        WHERE p.cod_produto = t.cod_produto

        /* TABELA metas_metas */
        UPDATE t
        SET t.cod_grupo = p.cod_empresa
        FROM metas_metas t
        JOIN produtos p ON p.cod_produto = t.cod_produto

        /* TABELA metas */
        UPDATE t
        SET t.cod_grupo = p.cod_empresa
        FROM metas t
        JOIN produtos p ON p.cod_produto = t.cod_produto

        /* TABELA itens_notasfiscais */
        UPDATE t
        SET t.cod_grupo = p.cod_empresa
        FROM itens_notasfiscais t
        JOIN produtos p ON p.cod_produto = t.cod_produto
        WHERE p.cod_produto = t.cod_produto

        /* TABELA cubo_rentabilidade */
        UPDATE t
        SET t.cod_grupo = p.cod_empresa
        FROM cubo_rentabilidade t
        JOIN produtos p ON p.cod_produto = t.cod_produto
        WHERE p.cod_produto = t.cod_produto

        /* TABELA cubo */
        UPDATE t
        SET t.cod_grupo = p.cod_empresa
        FROM cubo t
        JOIN produtos p ON p.cod_produto = t.cod_produto
        WHERE p.cod_produto = t.cod_produto

        /* TABELA logistica_sumario */
        UPDATE t
        SET t.cod_grupo = p.cod_empresa
        FROM logistica_sumario t
        JOIN produtos p ON p.cod_produto = t.cod_produto
        WHERE p.cod_produto = t.cod_produto

        /* TABELA produtos_sumario */
        UPDATE t
        SET t.cod_grupo = p.cod_empresa
        FROM produtos_sumario t
        JOIN produtos p ON p.cod_produto = t.cod_produto
        WHERE p.cod_produto = t.cod_produto

    END TRY
    BEGIN CATCH
        PRINT 'Falha ao atualizar campo cod_grupo dos registros';
        PRINT 'Erro ' + CONVERT(VARCHAR, ERROR_NUMBER(), 1) + ': '+ ERROR_MESSAGE()
    END CATCH
    GO
```

Comment: Marcelo, você pode usar esta dica: http://stackoverflow.com/a/5410799/1898543

Comment: Pode ser em forma de *procedure* ou você quer manter como *batch*?

Comment: Mantendo como batch, @CiganoMorrisonMendez

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Toda vez que você chamar o `GO` as variavés são descartadas. Então remova o `GO` do script